# How can seq evaluate an inifinite list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, infinite, seq, strictness

It is said that the Haskell **seq** function forces the evaluation of its first argument and returns the second. It is used to add strictness to evaluation of expressions. So how can the following simply return 5:

```
seq [1..] 5
```

Shouldn't it get stuck in trying to construct an infinite list?

Comment: `seq (undefined, undefined) True` won't evaluate the `undefined`s. Ditto for `seq (undefined : undefined) True`. This is because `seq` only evaluates enough to expose the first constructor, and does not go deep (also see `deepseq`).

Comment: Lists aren't really infinite. Skipping a lot of details, `seq` sees `[1..]` and evaluates it to `1 : [2..]`, then stops. The tail stays unevaluated until someone actually needs it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`seq` evaluates to *weak head normal form* (WHNF), which essentially means it evaluates one layer of data constructors. In this case, it means that it forces evaluation of the first cons cell (the `:` data constructor).

I have a pretty long post explaining details around this at https://haskell.fpcomplete.com/tutorial/all-about-strictness

Comment: Makes sense. I guess if you really want an infinite list to be evaluated (I mean get stuck into infinite recursion) you must give it a name and then ask for its length or something.

Comment: Or you can use something from the deepseq package